# Post photo by facebook sharedialog android

Tags: android, facebook, share, photo

May I know if there is a means to attach a photo by facebook sharedialog like below code?

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
.setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
.build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/#linkshare

Answer (score 0):

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
    .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
    .setPicture("https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png")
    .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```